# Each data input moves in repeated pattern. I.e starting in A2 -B2 -A3 -B3 -A4

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

how to create an excel vba where each data input moves in repeated pattern.  I.e starting in A2 -B2 -A3 -B3 -A4. Due to inputs from 2 sources - one will be rfid reader for animal identification tag and the other will be weight associated with that tag so need to be same row hence the movement to right then down to move to next ID.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far. It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. If it's data input (user puts in data), why is VBA involved?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.